# Validação CSRF dando erro depois de um tempo sem uso

Tags: php, codeigniter, segurança, csrf

tenho uma aplicação já rodando com codeigniter e estou com csrf habilitada no sistema. 
O problema esta em uma página que tem um formulário que envia para ela mesma, é um filtro, mas é o seguinte, o usuário faz o post e tem os resultados na tela, até ai esta tudo certo, mas se o usuário deixar a página aberta, dai vai e desliga o computador e num outro dia ele liga o PC e abre na mesma página me da um erro que o usuário não tem permissão `The action you have requested is not allowed.`. 
O que eu quero saber é se tem como pegar esse erro no _construct ou como posso saber desse erro para poder redirecionar o usuário para alguma outra página?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta para sua pergunta encontra-se aqui:
https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/207249/#964738

Basicamente, você deve extender a classe CI_Security. Para isso, crie um arquivo chamado MY_Security.php em application/core/ e altere a funcionalidade do método csrf_show_error() de acordo com o desejado:

```
class MY_Security extends CI_Security {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function csrf_show_error()
    {
        // adicione seu redirecionamento aqui
    }

}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Com certeza que ajudou, simples e direto.. Valew mesmo